# What is the input of tf.losses.log_loss(labels, predictions) in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

Anyone can give some examples ?
There is no guides in official document.
I want to know what type of labels and predictions are ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The inputs are tensors, the first one containing the correct prediction for your datapoint and the second is the actual prediction given by your model for the datapoint. These tensors can either represent a single datapoint, as in the example, or batches. They must have equal shape.

Examples:

```
import tensorflow as tf

""" Minimal example """
with tf.Session() as sess:
    loss = tf.losses.log_loss(tf.Variable([0., 1., 0.]), tf.Variable([0.1, 0.8, 0.1]))
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    result = sess.run(loss)
    print('Minimal example loss: %f' % result)

tf.reset_default_graph()

""" More realistic example """
with tf.Session() as sess:
    # Create placeholders for inputs
    X_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [3])
    y_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [3])

    # Set up the model structure, resulting in a set of predictions
    predictions = tf.multiply(X_placeholder, 2.)

    # Compute the loss of the calculated predictions
    loss = tf.losses.log_loss(y_placeholder, predictions)

    # Run the loss tensor with values for the placeholders
    result = sess.run(loss, feed_dict={X_placeholder: [0.5, 0.5, 0.5], y_placeholder: [0., 1., 0.]})
    print('Realistic example loss: %f' % result)
```

Comment: does `predictions` refer to logits or softmax probabilities? if so, why does it matter?